# ffmpeg video encoding strategy for preventing "inflating" of low quality videos

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

We're trying to build a php based video sharing site that allows users to upload their own content.

We need to convert all these videos into a medium-quality mp4 video file for eventual streaming through FlowPlayer.

Our code is something like this (example for flv):

```
system("ffmpeg -i $vidPath -pass 1 -ab 64k -ar 44100 -ac 1 -vcodec flv -b 1500k -cmp 3 -subcmp 3 -mbd 2 $flvPath");
```

The problem is that this converts any type of 1 minute video into a 10 MB file. If its a high quality 1 minute video, that gets converted to a 10 MB file - which is great. However, if its a low-quality video, say of just 2 MB, it will *still* get converted to a 10 MB file!!

What strategy / method should I adopt so that uploaded videos are "upper bound" in size, but lower quality videos of the same length dont get "inflated" to the same size!

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks for the accept.  I'm curious, which command line options did you end up using?

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502654/ffmpeg-bitrate-calculation-optimization, maybe some of the answers can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `-b` flag to force a bitrate.  What happens when you use the `-minrate` and `-maxrate` flags, [as listed in the documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC6) instead of setting a specific bitrate?

Another interesting option is `-fs`, which sets a maximum file size.  If you can determine the length of the video before encoding it, you can figure out what a good upper limit would be based on that length.