# FFMPEG Bitrate Calculation / Optimization

Tags: php, optimization, video, ffmpeg, bitrate

I wrote the following wrapper for FFMPEG:

```
function Video($input, $crop = null, $scale = null, $output = null, $extra = null)
{
    $input = @new ffmpeg_movie($input);

    if ((is_object($input) === true) && ($input->hasVideo() === true))
    {
        $size = array($input->getFrameWidth(), $input->getFrameHeight());
        $crop = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $crop), 'is_numeric'));
        $scale = array_values(array_filter(explode('*', $scale), 'is_numeric'));

        if ((is_callable('shell_exec') === true) && (is_executable($ffmpeg = trim(shell_exec('which ffmpeg'))) === true))
        {
            if (count($crop) == 2)
            {
                $crop = array($size[0] / $size[1], $crop[0] / $crop[1]);

                if ($crop[0] > $crop[1])
                {
                    $size[0] = round($size[1] * $crop[1]);
                }

                else if ($crop[0] < $crop[1])
                {
                    $size[1] = round($size[0] / $crop[1]);
                }

                $crop = array($input->getFrameWidth() - $size[0], $input->getFrameHeight() - $size[1]);
            }

            else
            {
                $crop = array(0, 0);
            }

            if (count($scale) >= 1)
            {
                if (empty($scale[0]) === true)
                {
                    $scale[0] = round($scale[1] * $size[0] / $size[1] / 2) * 2;
                }

                else if (empty($scale[1]) === true)
                {
                    $scale[1] = round($scale[0] * $size[1] / $size[0] / 2) * 2;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $scale = array(round($size[0] / 2) * 2, round($size[1] / 2) * 2);
            }

            $result = array();

            if (array_product($scale) > 0)
            {
                $result[] = sprintf('%s -i %s', escapeshellcmd($ffmpeg), escapeshellarg($input->getFileName()));

                if (array_sum($crop) > 0)
                {
                    if (stripos(shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($ffmpeg) . ' -h | grep crop'), 'removed') !== false)
                    {
                        $result[] = sprintf('-vf "crop=in_w-2*%u:in_h-2*%u"', round($crop[0] / 4) * 2, round($crop[1] / 4) * 2);
                    }

                    else if ($crop[0] > 0)
                    {
                        $result[] = sprintf('-cropleft %u -cropright %u', round($crop[0] / 4) * 2, round($crop[0] / 4) * 2);
                    }

                    else if ($crop[1] > 0)
                    {
                        $result[] = sprintf('-croptop %u -cropbottom %u', round($crop[1] / 4) * 2, round($crop[1] / 4) * 2);
                    }
                }

                if ($input->hasAudio() === true)
                {
                    $result[] = sprintf('-ab %u -ar %u', $input->getAudioBitRate(), $input->getAudioSampleRate());
                }

                $result[] = sprintf('-b %u -r %u -s %s', $input->getBitRate(), min(25, $input->getFrameRate()), implode('x', $scale));

                if (strlen($format = strtolower(ltrim(strrchr($output, '.'), '.'))) > 0)
                {
                    $result[] = sprintf('-f %s %s -y %s', $format, escapeshellcmd($extra), escapeshellarg($output . '.ffmpeg'));

                    if ((strncmp('flv', $format, 3) === 0) && (is_executable($flvtool2 = trim(shell_exec('which flvtool2'))) === true))
                    {
                        $result[] = sprintf('&& %s -U %s %s', escapeshellcmd($flvtool2), escapeshellarg($output . '.ffmpeg'), escapeshellarg($output . '.ffmpeg'));
                    }

                    $result[] = sprintf('&& mv -u %s %s', escapeshellarg($output . '.ffmpeg'), escapeshellarg($output));

                    if ((is_writable(dirname($output)) === true) && (is_resource($stream = popen('(' . implode(' ', $result) . ') 2>&1 &', 'r')) === true))
                    {
                        while (($buffer = fgets($stream)) !== false)
                        {
                            if (strpos($buffer, 'to stop encoding') !== false)
                            {
                                return (is_int(pclose($stream)) === true) ? true : false;
                            }
                        }

                        if (is_file($output . '.ffmpeg') === true)
                        {
                            unlink($output . '.ffmpeg');
                        }

                        pclose($stream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see I am using the original input audio and video bitrate in my output, even if the input video is cropped or resized, which seems pretty inefficient in terms of HD space.

I know very little about these matters but from my understanding bitrates are directly connected to the duration, quality and resolution of the media, right? If so, how can I use those values to determine an appropriate audio and video bitrate to maintain input quality and reduce the file size?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you shouldn't specify a bitrate at all. It's only useful for streaming, in which case you need to respect VBV as well (which specifies a maximum bitrate over time, as well as the average bitrate).

Use x264 crf 23 - its default constant-quality mode- and be happy. In the case of ffmpeg, this  is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i <file> -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -acodec copy <outfile>
```

As for audio, it's best directly copied if the input was compressed. This is not possible in some situations, such as if the input was vorbis and the output is a .flv file. In that case I would stick to whatever the default of the audio encoder selected is.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but the quality was crap. According to the FFMPEG documentation: **-b bitrate: Set the video bitrate in bit/s (default = 200 kb/s)**. As for the audio, I am limiting the bitrate to a maximum of 128kb. Also, since I'm kinda new to this, what does "crf 23" stands for?

Comment: Humm, I think I've found it in http://rob.opendot.cl/index.php/useful-stuff/ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide/: Constant Rate Factor. Do you know what it does exactly? Can I use it with other video codecs? And what about the 23, is there a scale?

Comment: No, it's an option specific to x264, which also has a different scale than other codecs. The mpeg4 equivalent is '-vqscale 2'. I'm not sure what the right options for vp8 or theora are.

Comment: @alex strange: Thank you for the explanation, where do you learn all this stuff from? I find the FFMPEG docs to be confusing, misleading and outdated...

Comment: By working on it and reading a lot of source code. I don't recommend this approach, since we're slowly driving towards making knowing this unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for the Shannon-Entropy -log(P)/log(2). This is the minimum bits any information can be think of. But I'm unsure if it is useful to you.

Comment: Never heard about Shannon-Entropy before, I'm gonna check the Wikipedia page now.

Comment: I took a glance at it but I don't understand how I can apply that to my problem with the variables I have available... Could you elaborate a bit more on this please?

Comment: Basically my idea is to count every symbol in your data and then sum it with Shannon-Entropy formula to get the least bits how your data can be compressed. This is a theoratical limit and it depends on your data and your algorithm. I believe it is only for text compression. But I'm very sure I'm wrong because I answered a similiar question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450489/how-does-winrar-perform-a-compression-ratio-check/5451331#5451331. user shelwien is a professional in compression.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I got from Wikipedia. However it's highly impractical to make PHP transverse every symbol in a large video and I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. A fuzzier and simpler calculation would be enough for me I guess.

Comment: Other thing you can do is using a space-filling-curve partitioning the video file and then take a few sample of your file and then calculate the shannon-entropy and let ffmpeg compress the sample too. shannon-entropy is only for accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [`-sameq` flag](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=965329), I read somewhere that this doesn't translate to the same quality but for now this is better than forcing the original bit rate.

Anyway, I've come across [this Bash script](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC6) that suggests that my thinking is right, I still don't know how to calculate the output bit rate without having the output size as a constrain. If anyone knows, please share!